# Import project from Eclipse to B4A?

Tags: eclipse, basic4android

I'm a beginner trying to learn my way through making my first real Android app. I actually started an app using Eclipse and have gotten pretty far with it. I'd like to be able to continue its development using B4A. Is it possible to bring my work from Eclipse into B4A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do, is to wrap your existing code as a library and then reference it from Basic4android. See this [video tutorial](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/showthread.php?p=69908).

Answer (score 0):

B4A is a language on its own and it has its own editor.

While, in theory, you can edit project files of a B4A application with any editor, I would assume that you used JAVA as your main programming language.

As B4A uses a language that close resembles (Visual) Basic that, in turns gets converted into JAVA while compiling, you have actually 2 choices in front of you if you want to use B4A:

1) the first is to port your project to B4A but this means that you will need to rewrite the code according to the B4A language specifications;

2) the second option would be to integrate your JAVA code running it inline : see [this forum post on the topic](https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/inline-java-code.50141/#content)

2) if you can pack whatever you wrote as a library module to be used later on by B4A, you could opt to do that: see [this forum post on the topic](https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/java-creating-libraries-for-basic4android.6810/#content)